# validation error on update_attributes of a subclass (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, subclass, sti

I implemented a signin/out machinery as Michael Hartl suggested in his tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out). All worked perfectly: creating, deleting, updating user from a profile page.

Then I created a `Teacher` model as a subclass of `User` (STI). It hasn't its own validation and should use the same validation as parent model (user).
But updating attributes for user with type = "Teacher" is no more possible (for the others users it continues to work). When I compile the update form it returns:

`error messages say me teacher.attributes.password is missing validation

while the teacher should inherit the same validation of user.

In routes.rb, after the creation of the teacher model I added:

```
 resources :teachers, :controller => 'users', :type => "Teacher"
```

This is the update method in the user controller:

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
   redirect_to @user   ...
```

If I change @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) to @user.update_attributes(params[:teacher]) It works, but obviously only for teacher.

I think the solution is quite easy but I'm a novice.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to the solution proposed by d11wtq here:

[Is subclassing a User model really bad to do in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146317/is-subclassing-a-user-model-really-bad-to-do-in-rails)

I edited the Teacher model like this:

```
class Teacher < User
```

`def self.model_name`

`User.model_name`

`end`

`end`